# Using width/height without units in HTML5

Tags: html, dom

Before HTML5, I use to set the width/height of an element through

```
element.style.width = 50
element.style.height = 100
```

and it used to consider 'px' as the default unit. After adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` all these are failing as I need to explicitly set the units while setting measurements. As I am using some of the libraries which used this style, its a lot of work to individually add 'px' to each of them. I am looking for a shim/polyfill to handle this automatically.

---

Thanks @Quentin.

We can't really use any shims/polyfill either since we are directly dealing with the DOM. Hence I greped the code for the pattern and fix them.

Comment: Requiring valid CSS isn't so much HTML 5 as it is [Standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). I'd strongly recommend fixing the libraries.

Comment: If you want crappy code to work, then stay in Quirks Mode – that’s _what it’s for_, after all.

Comment: Some browser developer tools can watch for changes to DOM attributes, letting you pause to note the callstack and fix the code. That might already be what you're doing, but just a step to make it easier...

Answer (score 0):

But adding px will give you a

> Bad value (*number*)px for attribute height on element img: Expected a digit but saw p

if you put it into an HTML validator